# How to parse the string into map

Tags: java

have a string like A=B&C=D&E=F, how to parse it into map?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I would use split

```
String text = "A=B&C=D&E=F";
Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
for(String keyValue : text.split(" *& *")) {
   String[] pairs = keyValue.split(" *= *", 2);
   map.put(pairs[0], pairs.length == 1 ? "" : pairs[1]);
}
```

EDIT allows for padded spaces and a value with an `=` or no value. e.g.

```
A = minus- & C=equals= & E==F
```

Comment: +1. In process of writing identical code. Depends partly on how much error checking the code needs to do. Is this toy code? Does this need to copy with badly formed input etc? Code here will give arrayIndexException if there is no '=' for example, but that may be just fine in the scenario.

Comment: It will handle an `=` in the value rather than chopping it off ;)

Answer (score 7):

just use guava Splitter

```
String src="A=B&C=D&E=F";
Map map= Splitter.on('&').withKeyValueSeparator('=').split(src)；
```

Answer (score 5):

```
public class TestMapParser {
    @Test
    public void testParsing() {
        Map<String, String> map = parseMap("A=B&C=D&E=F");
        Assert.assertTrue("contains key", map.containsKey("A"));
        Assert.assertEquals("contains value", "B", map.get("A"));

        Assert.assertTrue("contains key", map.containsKey("C"));
        Assert.assertEquals("contains value", "D", map.get("C"));

        Assert.assertTrue("contains key", map.containsKey("E"));
        Assert.assertEquals("contains value", "F", map.get("E"));
    }

    private Map<String, String> parseMap(final String input) {
        final Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (String pair : input.split("&")) {
            String[] kv = pair.split("=");
            map.put(kv[0], kv[1]);
        }
        return map;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String  t = A=B&C=D&E=F;
Map map = new HashMap();
String[] pairs = t.split("&");
//TODO 1) Learn generis 2) Use gnerics    
for (String pair : pairs)
{
    String[] kv = pair.split("=");
    map.put(kv[0], kv[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Split the string (either using a `StringTokenizer` or `String.split()`) on '&'. On each token just split again on '='. Use the first part as the key and the second part as the value.

It can also be done using a regex, but the problem is really simple enough for `StringTokenizer`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the stream api it can be done in just one expression.

```
String  t = "A=B&C=D&E=F";
Map<String, String> map = Arrays.stream(t.split("&"))
.map(kv -> kv.split("="))
.collect(Collectors.toMap(kv -> kv[0], kv -> kv[1]));
```