# Extract varaibles and values from a string

Tags: java, regex

I have a string that looks like this:
String info = "var1=value1;var2=value2;var3=value3;" ;

What would be your approach to extract each var name and value in Java?

Any ideas would be appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: mmm why don't you better split the string by the char ";" then each of them by the "="  ? Not pretty, bu will do the work. also please post any attempt you have tried (code)

Comment: You should rather use a list to put those values in, instead of having the program change its own source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another user asked a similar question. The user wanted to know how to parse a string "A=B&C=D&E=F" into a map. Your string looks almost the same. It got keys and values too.

Using a map would be the easiest way to have a clear structure. Take a look at the following question and the provided answer:

[How to parse the string into map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153252/how-to-parse-the-string-into-map)

*Extracted part of the answer:*

> I would use split
>
> ```
> String text = "A=B&C=D&E=F";
>
> Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
>
> for(String keyValue : text.split(" *& *")) {
>     String[] pairs = keyValue.split(" *= *", 2);
>     map.put(pairs[0], pairs.length == 1 ? "" : pairs[1]);
> }
> ```
>
> EDIT allows for padded spaces and a value with an = or no value. e.g.
>
> `A = minus- & C=equals= & E==F`

It shows how you could split a string like yours in key-value pairs and save those in a map.

This would be my choice to split your string and storage the information.

Comment: Please provide a better summary of your link. As written, your post would be a better comment than an answer (although, I know you don't have the rep yet to post comments).

Answer (score 2):

You can try using following regex,

```
(\w+)=(\w+);
```

[Working Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nU7mZ7/1)

It uses the concept of [Group capture](http://regexone.com/lesson/11)

Answer (score 1):

I would probably just go with String.split() (untested):

```
for (String s : info.split(":") {
     String[] pair = s.split("=");
     HashMap.put(pair[0],pair[1]);     // Or whatever you do with the data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping me out with this. I have read about regex and I'm more familiar with it now. I admit I should go through the tutorials first before I asked the question (lesson learned). I was bit under pressure so that was easier was just ask someone :)
I have used the method suggested Hudi:

```
    public class ArduinoResponsePhraser {
```

```
        Map varMap = new HashMap();

        public Map PhraseString(String response)
        {
                for (String s : response.split(";")) {
                        String[] pair = s.split("=");
                        varMap.put(pair[0], pair[1]);
                }
                return varMap;
        }
```